# Pandas group by and keep ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame like this:

| temp_id | administ_div | municipality | combine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gunma | Maebashi |  |
| NaN | Gunma | Maebashi | CC |
| NaN | Gunma | Maebashi | DD |
| NaN | Gunma | Maebashi | EE |
| 2 | Gunma | Kiryu | AA |

How do I group by `administ_div`, `municipality` to this (temp_id must be not NaN):

| temp_id | administ_div | municipality | combine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gunma | Maebashi | [CC,DD,EE] |
| 2 | Gunma | Kiryu | AA |

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with help of [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
# aggregate all columns with first value
agg_funcs = {c: 'first' for c in df}
# except "combine" as list of non-null values
agg_funcs['combine'] = lambda l: [x for x in l if x]

# group by filled values and aggregate
out = (df
 .groupby(df['temp_id'].ffill(), as_index=False)
 .agg(agg_funcs)
)
```

output:

```
   temp_id administ_div municipality       combine
0      1.0        Gunma     Maebashi  [CC, DD, EE]
1      2.0        Gunma        Kiryu          [AA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['temp_id'] = df['temp_id'].ffill()
df1 = df.groupby(['temp_id', 'administ_div', 'municipality'])['combine'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if not pd.isna(i)][0] if len(x)==1 else [i for i in x if not pd.isna(i)]).reset_index()

df1
    temp_id administ_div    municipality    combine
0   1.0     Gunma           Maebashi        [CC, DD, EE]
1   2.0     Gunma           Kiryu           AA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = (df.assign(temp_id=df.temp_id.ffill())
         .groupby(['temp_id', 'administ_div', 'municipality'], as_index=False)['combine']
         .agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   temp_id administ_div municipality       combine
0      1.0        Gunma     Maebashi  [CC, DD, EE]
1      2.0        Gunma        Kiryu          [AA]
```